# axis2 xsd:date format issue

Tags: apache-axis

In WSDL I have the following format:

USER_ACT_STRDT is a date.

When I generate the STUB (using Axis2 1.5.3), the generated stub (ADB Data Binding) has the following source code :

public void setUSER_ACT_STRDT_TypeDef(Date param) {

if (ConverterUtil.convertToString(param).matches("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")) {

this.localUSER_ACT_STRDT_TypeDef=param; } else { throw new java.lang.RuntimeException();
} }

This method always throws RuntimeException because the ConverterUtil.convertToString() method returns a String in a different format than "yyyy-mm-dd". It returns the date by appending +5.30 as 2011-03-21+05:30.

I tried passing the date in different formats but same result for all.

Can any one suggest how to resolve this issue.